# How to serve images as "SSL" based in WORDPRESS

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl

If you open this attached image you can see that my site pas lock is not working fine due to un secure images.
can any body help me to resolve this issue ? My site is wordpress based and url of my site is https://designinsist.com/
Thanks in advance.

[image: RESULT OF MY TEST INCASE IF YOU DON'T WANT TO PERFORM BY YOUR SELF]

Answer (score 0):

[Fixed Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqRq4.png) 
I fixed this issue just by uploading those images again with "https".
That's what i did and my ssl is working fine.